# Javascript regex matching syntax not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to test a string to ensure it has the following pattern:

```
asas/asas2/asas
```

The charatcers in between the slashes can be letters, digits or both.

---

#### I have a working example here, although i'm sure it could be improved.

[**Regex Example**](http://regexr.com/3g9ku)

---

#### But when tested in jsfiddle it doesn't work

[**Jsfiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/32qscfuj/)

```
var str = 'dfdfdf/dfdf/dfdf';
var patt = new RegExp("/(^\w+\/\w+\/\w+$)/g");
var res = patt.test(str);
alert(res);
```

The above code example always returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes `new RegExp(/(^\w+\/\w+\/\w+$)/g);`

Answer (score 2):

You just have to remove quotes.

```js
var str = 'dfdfdf/dfdf/dfdf';
var patt = /(^\w+\/\w+\/\w+$)/g;
var res = patt.test(str);
alert(res);
```

Comment: ...and the RegExp constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
var str = 'dfdfdf/dfdf/dfdf';
var patt = new RegExp(/(^\w+\/\w+\/\w+$)/g);
var res = patt.test(str);
alert(res);
console.log(res);
```

Thanks